# django weird migration issue - ProgrammingError: column does not exist - seemingly only within Celery?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, celery

I have a django app a docker-compose setup, also using celery. I am receiving an error relating to a model field that I recently deleted.  I only noticed there was an issue when calling a certain function within a celery task.

Some notes:

- I've confirmed the column no longer exists in the db
- I have ran makemigrations and migrate, django says everything is all good
- The only place the field is referenced in my project is in migration files

The error I am receiving:

```
celery         | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
celery         |
celery         | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
celery         |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 734, in __protected_call__
celery         |     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
celery         |   File "/code/src/leads/tasks.py", line 71, in try_to_sell_lead
celery         |     results = lead.get_contracts_qualified_for_in_sell_order(to_contract_ids, ignore_contract_filters,
celery         |   File "/code/src/leads/models.py", line 339, in get_contracts_qualified_for_in_sell_order
celery         |     elif not contract.has_enough_credit():
celery         |   File "/code/src/contracts/models.py", line 261, in has_enough_credit
celery         |     for batch in batches:
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 398, in __iter__
celery         |     self._fetch_all()
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1881, in _fetch_all
celery         |     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 91, in __iter__
celery         |     results = compiler.execute_sql(
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1560, in execute_sql
celery         |     cursor.execute(sql, params)
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
celery         |     return self._execute_with_wrappers(
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
celery         |     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
celery         |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
celery         |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
celery         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
celery         |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
celery         | django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column contracts_contractcreditbatch.initial_credit_balance does not exist
celery         | LINE 1: ..., "contracts_contractcreditbatch"."batch_number", "contracts...
```

It seems like the error is triggered within the 'has_enough_credit' method within my contract model.  This is the method:

```
    def has_enough_credit(self):
        batches = self.credit_batches.filter(depleted=False)
        for batch in batches:
            if batch.credit_balance >= self.base_price_per_lead:
                return True
            else:
                batch.deplete_batch(remove_credit=False)
        return False
```

Judging by the traceback the last part of my code it references is `for batch in batches`.  So something funky is happening when trying to access a batch instance?

**The really weird thing** is that when I call this same method on the same contract that it fails on, but from within the django python shell, it works fine and doesn't error out.  I am really confused by this, could that mean something could be out of sync within celery's configuration?  Why would it work without db errors within shell but not within a celery task?

Comment: have you restarted the celery service?

Comment: Oh man, I've been doing docker-compose up without --build flag.  I didn't realise I would need to, but I've just done it and it is now working.  Thanks heaps!

Comment: somewhere in your task, you've imported the model that changed, but celery still has the 'old' version in memory and will make calls based on the version it imported when last started - that's how I picture it anyway. Restarting the service will do the imports again, thus getting the 'new' shape of the model.